# Convert a list of list to columns in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

i have a dataframe of numpy arrays such as below:

```
            col1
0       [[1,2,3,4,5,5]]
1       [[3,4,5,6,7,8]]
2       [[2,3,4,1,2,1]]
....
```

how to convert this dataframe to a dataframe like:

```
    col1  col2  col3  col4  col5  col6
0     1     2     3    4      5     6
1     3     4     5    6      7     8
2     2     3     4    1      2     1
....
```

my code is wrong:

```
pf = pd.DataFrame(df[0].values.tolist())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
In [27]: df
Out[27]:
                   col1
0  [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5]]
1  [[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]]
2  [[2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 1]]

In [28]: df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x[0][0]), axis=1)
Out[28]:
   0  1  2  3  4  5
0  1  2  3  4  5  5
1  3  4  5  6  7  8
2  2  3  4  1  2  1
```

And for the column names, something to the effect of:

```
In [29]: df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x[0][0]), axis=1).rename(columns=lambda x: f"col{x+1}")
Out[29]:
   col1  col2  col3  col4  col5  col6
0     1     2     3     4     5     5
1     3     4     5     6     7     8
2     2     3     4     1     2     1
```

Comment: Thank you, drops this error : Exception: ('Data must be 1-dimensional', u'occurred at index 0')

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [[[1,2,3,4,5,5]],
                            [[3,4,5,6,7,8]],
                            [[2,3,4,1,2,1]]]})

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([x[0] for x in df['col1'].values]),
                  columns=['col'+str(i) for i in range(1, 7)])

#    col1  col2  col3  col4  col5  col6
# 0     1     2     3     4     5     5
# 1     3     4     5     6     7     8
# 2     2     3     4     1     2     1
```

Comment: This is the fastest solution in my testing.

Answer (score 0):

Unwrap the outer list from each entry, then use the vectorized `.values.tolist()`, then pass into a DataFrame constructor and rename:

```
pd.DataFrame(df['col1'].apply(lambda x: x[0]).values.tolist()).rename(columns=lambda x: 'col{}'.format(x+1))
```